# Angular child route does not activate

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular routing in combination with [ngx-translate-router](https://github.com/gilsdav/ngx-translate-router), and I'm having a strange issue with child routes. I'm not sure if it's related to the translated router module that I'm using, but the application is too complex already to take it apart.

The issue seems to be that my routing only works when reloading the page directly. When I'm trying to navigate using `[routerLink]="['/admin', 'users']"`, no error occurs, I see the traces of the router being printed in the console, and when traversing the router tree I even see the component it is supposed to load listed, but it is never activated.

```ts
// app.module.ts

const appRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: "",
    loadChildren: () => import("./auth/auth.module").then(m => m.AuthModule),
    data: {
        discriminantPathKey: "AUTHPATH",
        skipRouteLocalization: true
    }
}, {
    path: "admin",
    loadChildren: () => import("./admin/admin.module").then(m => m.AdminModule),
    data: {
        discriminantPathKey: "ADMINPATH",
        skipRouteLocalization: true
    }
}, {
    path: "",
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [{
        path: "",
        component: SidebarComponent,
        children: [{
            path: "",
            component: CitiesListComponent
        }, {
            path: "search",
            component: SearchComponent
        }, {
            path: ":cityId",
            component: CityComponent,
            children: [{
                path: "",
                redirectTo: "locations",
                pathMatch: "full"
            }, {
                path: "locations",
                component: LocationsListComponent,
                children: [{
                    path: ":locationId",
                    component: LocationComponent
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}];
```

The module it then loads has the following set up

```ts
// admin/admin.module.ts

import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { NgbModule } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { SharedModule } from "../shared/shared.module";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { AuthModule } from "../auth/auth.module";
import { AdminRoutingModule } from "./admin-routing.module";
import { UsersService } from "./services/users.service";
import { DashboardComponent } from "./components/dashboard/dashboard.component";
import { NavigationComponent } from "./components/navigation/navigation.component";
import { UsersComponent } from "./components/users/users.component";
import { AdminComponent } from "./admin.component";


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        NgbModule,
        SharedModule,
        AdminRoutingModule,
        AuthModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AdminComponent,
        DashboardComponent,
        NavigationComponent,
        UsersComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        UsersService
    ],
    exports: [
        AdminRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class AdminModule {
}
```

And this is the routing module it then imports

```ts
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { TranslateModule } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { LocalizeRouterModule } from "@gilsdav/ngx-translate-router";
import { DashboardComponent } from "./components/dashboard/dashboard.component";
import { AdminComponent } from "./admin.component";
import { UsersComponent } from "./components/users/users.component";

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: "",
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [{
        path: "",
        component: DashboardComponent,
        pathMatch: "full"
    }, {
        path: "users",
        component: UsersComponent
    }]
}];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        TranslateModule.forChild(),
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        LocalizeRouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule,
        LocalizeRouterModule
    ]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule {}
```

How do I find where my routing causes problems? I've tried debugging by manually editing the compiled JavaScript files, but this sadly doesn't work very well.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem without ngx-translate-router? It should be relatively simple to set up a stackblitz with a similar module setup and routing request.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies within the `npx-translate-router` module. While debugging, I modified the `GilsdavReuseStrategy` to return `false` on the `shouldReuseRoute` method, and suddenly routing worked again. It caused some other issues, but at least it switched pages.

This is a problem that should be taken to the author of the package.